# Weblogic 12C + SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, weblogic, sql-server-2012, weblogic12c

I've been trying to get the following setup to work for the last few days:

- Weblogic 12c application server
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database
- Java application

I keep running into the same problem:

`java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver]This driver is locked for use with embedded applications.`

On the Oracle website, i found that Weblogic 12c supports SQL Server 2008 `and up` .. but I'm starting to have my doubts about this being true for SQL Server 2012 ..

Has anyone been able to get this configuration running and/or does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 more days of searching, I found out that the correct amount of dependencies has to be added to the classpath:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlsqlserver</artifactId>
        <version>12c</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>12c</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlclient</artifactId>
        <version>12c</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hey I know this post is a bit old but I am running into a similar issue. Exact same stack (Java 1.8, WebLogic 12.1.3, MS SQL Server 2014). The dependencies are not resolving and I'm not sure what to do. Did you have to manually download the jars and install in maven before they resolved?